# Haskell: Using map with a function that returns a list?

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

I have this encode function:

```
class Encode a where
  encode :: a -> [Bit]
```

and I have problems writing a function that encodes a list of type a to a list of bits. I want to recursively encode the elements of a list. In my understanding you can use the map function for that purpose. The problem is that encode returns a list [Bit], whereas map expects just Bit. How can I solve this? Here is the relevant part of the program.

```
instance Encode a => Encode [a] where
    encode [] = [I, O, O, I, O, I]
    encode m = ([I, O, O] ++ (map encode m) ++ [I, O, I])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`concatMap`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:concatMap). It `concat`enates the results after `map`ping them.

```
instance Encode a => Encode [a] where
    encode [] = [I, O, O, I, O, I]
    encode m = ([I, O, O] ++ (concatMap encode m) ++ [I, O, I])
```

How you could have found this out for yourself: if you search for the type of the function you want, [`(a -> [Bit]) -> [a] -> [Bit]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20[Bit]%29%20-%3E%20[a]%20-%3E%20[Bit]), using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), `concatMap` is the first result.

Comment: You don't even need to special-case the empty list, @user2367390, it's also covered by the second equation.

Comment: Following up on the comment about Hoogle--a useful approach to such situations is to put a custom function in place, define it with undefined, and then use ghci to find the type (`:t function`). That shows you the type the compiler infers; that can help writing the function, or you can search for the signature with Hoogle.

(Here that would mean defining `encode m = ([I, O, O] ++ (map' encode m) ++ [I, O, I])` and `map' = undefined`; loading in ghci and typing `:t map'`).